# Managing similar workflows in .git

Tags: git, version-control, latex, workflow, project

I am managing two versions of my resume in git. One has an experience that the other does not, but other major updates (even small things), I would like to update both. I've noticed that I keep two local branches that push to different remote branches, but I have to constantly update both (manually) whenever I make a change in one. Is there any way to manage this sort of workflow in git, and if not, what is the best solution for productivity?

For example, let's say I change my resume, then I have to change it in both. It is just about 4 lines of text (along with minor formatting things like `\vskip Xpt`) that are different in each.

Comment: I would manage it in a single branch, but keeping the two parts separate with a "build job" like github actions or a Jenkins file to produce the two separate editions by combining the two parts in one and only creating the other with that part alone.

That way you only have one branch, two LATEX files and a workflow  (or two) to publish the two documents

Comment: Could you please elaborate @JoSSte or post an answer ? This is one file, that has some minor differences.

Comment: I have written an answer for you. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single version of your CV by writing the experience into a separate file and then include the experience when you need it or comment it out if you don't need it.

Initial version (example)

```
...
\vspace{2em}
%Experience
1980 -- present & Job title \\
                & \small{description}\\
1978 -- 1980 & Lemonade stand \\
             & \small{Selling lemonade} \\
\vspace{2em}
%Education
...
```

You can then put the experience part into the second file (including spaces). So for the example you would put the following into the second file (e.g. fileB.tex):

```
\vspace{2em}
%Experience
1980 -- present & Job title \\
                & \small{description}\\
1978 -- 1980 & Lemonade stand \\
             & \small{Selling lemonade} \\
```

Next, you replace the old experience part in your CV by `\include{fileB}`:

```
...
\input{fileB.tex} %comment out to compile without experience
\vspace{2em}
%Education
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm git savvy not LaTeX savvy. this is my first LaTeX document ever.

That said, This is how I would do it (inspired by [Conditional Import in LaTeX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655454/conditional-import-in-latex))

I would split my document up into sections. I have chosen header, footer, resume and references in this case:

Then I made two .tex files:

### withReferences.tex

```latex
\include{header}
\include{resume}
\include{references}
\include{footer}
```

### withoutReferences.tex

```latex
\include{header}
\include{resume}
\include{footer}
```

When you compile the `withReferences.tex` file you get the complete document, if you compile the `withoutReferences.tex` you get the document without the references. This gives you one set of files to maintain.

If you don't like this approach, [the answer I referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3655553/1725871) provides another approach which I don't understand completely. But I guess the gist of it is that you create an boolean environment variable, and based on that, your list of references are included.

### Example files I used to test:

#### header.tex

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\title{Resume of JoSSte}
\author{Josste}
\date{July 2023}
\begin{document}
   \maketitle
   My resume!
   \tableofcontents{}
```

#### footer.tex

```latex
\end{document}
```

#### references.tex

```latex
\section{References}
\begin{itemize}
  \item random bullets from https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Lists
  \item List entries start with the \verb|\item| command.
  \item Individual entries are indicated with a black dot, a so-called bullet.
  \item The text in the entries may be of any length.
\end{itemize}
```

#### .tex

```latex
\section{Resume}

Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit amen
```

i put it on [github](https://github.com/JoSSte/LaTEX) too